# Why won't my program compile?

Tags: java, string, loops

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CodeSnippetm01 {
    public static void main(final String[] args, int len) {
        //0. Variable declarations.
        String greeting = "Welcome to CST242!";
        String question1 = "What is your name?:";

        //1. Print Statement.

        System.out.println(greeting);
        System.out.println(question1);

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        len = input.length();
        //2. Code for prompt and input
        while (len > 0) {

            String input = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.println("String Length is : " + len);

            //3. Loop code and loop body.
        }
        //4. Multiway If block.
    }
}
```

I have to create a loop that displays a single character on each line from the person’s name, input an integer representing the person’s age in 2 using a Scanner method and then use a multiway if-else statement to print the following (shown in Pseudocode):

```
If the person is >= 90, print `({name from 2} +“was born before 1923.”)`. 

Else if person >=75, print `({name from 2} +“was born born before 1938.”)`. 

Else if person >=50, print `({name from 2} +“was born born before 1963.”)`. 

Else if person >=25, print `({name from 2} +“was born born before 1988.”)`. 

Else print `({name from 2} +“was born born sometime after 1988.”)`
```

So far this is what I have.. any recommendations or help is welcome :-)

Comment: Instead of asking us "why doesn't it compile?", provide the *actual* compiler error messages.

Comment: There are a number of problems in your code.  However, you are going to need to LEARN to find these things for yourself.  Start by READING the compilation error messages.  Please don't expect SO to provide you with one-on-one tutoring.  (Or a "finish my homework" service.)  If you need that kind of help, you should talk to your lecturer / teacher.

Comment: @eebbesen Formatting is fine, but please don't add keywords such as `final` to the code as they may influence the compiler (I can understand why you hit "Clean" on the code though :) )

Comment: @owlstead Thanks for catching that.  A good reminder to make sure to disable my normal save actions when using an IDE to format stuff for SO :).

Comment: Have you thought about using a `do/while` loop instead of a `while`?  I'm assuming that the condition `len > 0` is there so that the user can quit out of the program by entering a blank line.  If that's the case, it makes more sense to check it at the bottom of the loop, rather than the top; and that's what `do/while` loops do.

Answer (score 1):

`input` is not defined before its used. Retry with following code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CodeSnippetm01 {

    public static void main(String[] args, int len) {
        //0. Variable declarations.
        String greeting = "Welcome to CST242!";
        String question1 = "What is your name?:";

        //1. Print Statement.
        System.out.println(greeting);
        System.out.println(question1);
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = keyboard.nextLine();
        len = input.length();
        //2. Code for prompt and input
        while (len > 0) {
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("String Length is : " + len);
            //3. Loop code and loop body.
        }
        //4. Multiway If block.
    }
}
```